# Birt - How to display a default value for a data row element

Tags: birt

So I want a field in my table to show the value from the data if it is not blank, and show some text otherwise.

I tried using this as my expression:

```
dataSetRow["date_billed"] || "Not Yet Billed"
```

But it didn't seem to work.

Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: Can you specify the language in the tags?  You'll probably get a lot more views.

Comment: Birt is a reporting tool based on Eclipse.  I guess it seems to want Javascript or some subset of it in the expression editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the existing data field with a Dynamic Text report item, containing the following expression:

```
{row["date_billed"]>"" ? row["date_billed"] : "Not Yet Billed"}
```